# How to detect an image Object on tensor-flow?

Tags: android, tensorflow

I want to detect an object of image in android app

so, anybody help me.

Comment: Hi Karan Chunara, did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to detect a custom object in an image.
For custom object [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U) is a great tutorial.

After training clone [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) GitHub repository; it has an Android example in the directory **tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/android**

Place your model & label file in **assets** folder.

Open above cloned project in the android studio, it will ask you to sync Gradle; open **DetectorActivity.java** file; replace the model & label file name with your's in below 2 variable names.

TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE  &

TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE

Run the android project, on your device 4 apps will get installed from which TF_Detect is your desired app

Hope this helps you...